# QScopedPointer declaration in header, definition in src

Tags: qt

Can you have a QScopedPointer declared in a header:

```
QScopedPointer <T> _name;
```

And in the .cpp definition/instantiation:

```
_name ( /*new T*/ );
```

Note: i am aware that QScopedPointer doesn't have the operator to do this, only a ctor, but conceptually, can this be inplemented somehow?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use `QScopedPointer<T>`-typed class member in the header with our
>   class declaration?

Yes. Make sure that the type `T` either defined or declared:

```
///
/// File MyClass.h
///

// Either have:
#include "MyType.h" // defines MyType

// Or:
class MyType; // forward declaraion

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ////
private:
    QScopedPointer<MyType> m_pTypeObj;
};
```

But you should always have the type defined where you instantiate the object and store the pointer in that `QScopedPointer<MyType>`:

```
#include "MyClass.h" // defines MyClass
// If not through MyClass.h then must have:
#include "MyType.h"  // defines MyType

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // now we can instantiate MyType
    m_pTypeObj.reset(new MyType);
    // and use the scoped pointer
    m_pTypeObj->method();
}
```

Or maybe as the author implies:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : m_pTypeObj(new MyType)
{
    // and use the scoped pointer
    m_pTypeObj->method();
}
```

The approach is also applicable to [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which can now replace [QScopedPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html).

Comment: First sample won't compile, because default dtor will need definition of the object. If you want to use QScopedPointer with forward declaration you must define dtor in .cpp file.

Comment: Correct: * But you should always have the type defined where you instantiate the object *